# How to reset global object in embedded V8?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I would like to be able to reset global object of my V8 JS context. Let's say everything works fine, code executes etc. But now I would like to return to my starting state (remove all objects, functions etc.)

I tried this way:

First I leave my current context:

```
v8::Local<v8::Context> context(m_isolate->GetCurrentContext());
context->Exit();

m_context.Reset(); //v8::Global<v8::Context>
```

And I create new context with new global object:

```
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(m_isolate);
global->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
install_global_functions(global);

v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(m_isolate, nullptr, global);
m_context.Reset(m_isolate, context); //making context persistent

context->Enter();

v8::Local<v8::Object> g_obj = context->Global();
g_obj->SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(0, this);
```

And...
I still have access to variables, functions, classes I defined in previous context. WHY? How is this possible. When I create a new context with new global object template shouldn't it be just a 'clean' instance? What is wrong?

What I want to do is just clear everything (stuff that was created in JS and stuff that was added to global object from C++ both)? Is there any way to do this (other then destroying an isolate and reinitializing everything)?

**EDIT:**

It seems like `isolate->GetCurrentContext()` isn't returning correct context. I'm using this method frequently to find 'current' context. Tried two different methods `isolate->GetEnteredContext()` and `m_context.Get(m_isolate)` and this two **seem** to work correctly. I still don't understand WHY? Why `isolate->GetCurrentContext()` is returning old context while it's name suggests otherwise??? What does `isolate->GetCurrentContext()` actually return? I'm lost...

Answer (score 0):

`isolate->GetCurrentContext()` returns the last `Enter()`-ed context...